# Eclipse Crashing After Splash Screen

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I am trying to install Eclipse Standard 4.3.2 (https://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-standard-432/keplersr2) on OSX 10.10.5 (most up to date version of Yosemite).

My Java version is:
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)

For some reason, whenever I open Eclipse, I see the splash screen. It loads for a few seconds than crashes and disappears from my dock. Below is the crash report from the output log. After many hours of trying to figure this out, I can't seem to come up with anything. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
!SESSION 2015-09-03 14:42:43.190 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.3.2.M20140221-1700
java.version=1.8.0_60
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product -keyring /Users/Sydney/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product -keyring /Users/Sydney/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2015-09-03 14:42:52.123
!MESSAGE System property http.nonProxyHosts has been set to local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16 by an external source. This value will be overwritten using the values from the preferences

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-09-03 14:42:52.599
!MESSAGE An unexpected runtime error has occurred.
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4397)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4312)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4283)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.error(Display.java:1076)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Display.java:833)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Display.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Device.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:707)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:698)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getDefault(Display.java:1396)
    at org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin.refreshPluginActions(AbstractUIPlugin.java:484)
    at org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin$2.bundleChanged(AbstractUIPlugin.java:602)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:847)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler 4 0 2015-09-03 14:42:52.608
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4397)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4312)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4283)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.error(Display.java:1076)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Display.java:833)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Display.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Device.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:707)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:698)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getDefault(Display.java:1396)
    at org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin.refreshPluginActions(AbstractUIPlugin.java:484)
    at org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin$2.bundleChanged(AbstractUIPlugin.java:602)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:847)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 2 2015-09-03 14:42:52.684
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in "org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler" was unable to instantiate class "org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler.AutomaticUpdateScheduler".
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.getExecutableExtension(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$55.run(Workbench.java:2555)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler.AutomaticUpdateScheduler.<init>(AutomaticUpdateScheduler.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
    ... 11 more
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.registry 4 1 2015-09-03 14:42:52.686
!MESSAGE Plug-in "org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler" was unable to instantiate class "org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler.AutomaticUpdateScheduler".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler.AutomaticUpdateScheduler.<init>(AutomaticUpdateScheduler.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.getExecutableExtension(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$55.run(Workbench.java:2555)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.registry 4 1 2015-09-03 14:42:52.686
!MESSAGE Plug-in "org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler" was unable to instantiate class "org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler.AutomaticUpdateScheduler".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler.AutomaticUpdateScheduler.<init>(AutomaticUpdateScheduler.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.getExecutableExtension(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$55.run(Workbench.java:2555)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2015-09-03 14:42:52.694
!MESSAGE Unhandled Exception

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler 4 0 2015-09-03 14:42:52.694
!MESSAGE Unable to execute early startup code for an extension
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in "org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler" was unable to instantiate class "org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler.AutomaticUpdateScheduler".
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.getExecutableExtension(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$55.run(Workbench.java:2555)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler.AutomaticUpdateScheduler.<init>(AutomaticUpdateScheduler.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
    ... 11 more
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.registry 4 1 2015-09-03 14:42:52.695
!MESSAGE Plug-in "org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler" was unable to instantiate class "org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler.AutomaticUpdateScheduler".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler.AutomaticUpdateScheduler.<init>(AutomaticUpdateScheduler.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.getExecutableExtension(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$55.run(Workbench.java:2555)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Comment: Is there some reason you are installing release 4.3 instead of the current release 4.5?

Answer (score 1):

Try to start Eclipse with both `-nosplash` and `-clean`. Sounds improbable, but something appears to be creating the default display earlier than the workbench itself. This is usually a noob mistake in RCP programming, so I'm sceptical how that should happen in a standard vanilla Eclipse, but let's try this first and we'll see if this gets you anywhere.